# Office 365 University Availability of Office 2013 and Auto-Updates to Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-office-365

For students who download and use the free Office 365 University, will Office 2013 auto-update to Office 2016, or will students be able to keep Office 2013 until September of 2016? Also, will new students still be able to download Office 2013 going forward? Many classes, especially software app classes rely on that version and cannot use Office 2016 until new books and materials are available.

Answer (score 3):

1. You want to review [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-do-I-update-Office-to-Office-2016-using-Office-365-for-business-35d332d7-ee81-40e3-99d2-1a4eed2efb52) and [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-do-I-upgrade-to-Office-2016-if-I-have-an-Office-365-subscription-ee68f6cf-422f-464a-82ec-385f65391350?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
2. Your IT department (maybe you?) should be able to address your concerns by using the Office Deployment Tools or looking at the O365 admin options for the University tenants they control to prevent the users from automatically installing the latest updates (such as changing from First Release)
3. Look at the answer here https://serverfault.com/a/724061/7861 as it should address your answers as well, but University is a little different...so you may want to ask your Microsoft TAM or rep directly.

Comment: I suspect the GPO is going to be playing with registry keys that could be turned into a hack for home use...

Comment: @RobM - yep I noticed that and removed that portion...